# Unexpected content-type can cause two different exceptions depending on the rest resource

Tags: quarkus

I have been implementing a jax-rs resource in Quarkus which needs to use media type versioning. Unfortunately, Quarkus doesn't seem to be consistent wrt. which exceptions are thrown.

If somebody tries to access the jax-rs resource with an unexpected content-type, two different exceptions are thrown depending on the number of methods implemented inside the REST resource. If the resource only has a single method, the thrown exception is a jakarta.ws.rs.NotSupportedException but when the resource has more than one method an jakarta.ws.rs.WebApplicationException is thrown.

It is not really the biggest problem in the world, but my exception mappers got confused and I ended up spending quite some time debugging my application.

I don't believe (not 100% sure) that I have seen this problem before I started using the quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb extension (resteasy-reactive is recommended by quarkus instead of just using resteasy). I have used quarkus-resteasy-jsonb previously.

My questions are: 1) Did I do anything wrong which can cause the problem, 2) if I haven't done something stupid, is this a bug in Quarkus or just a feature? and 3) Has anyone experienced similar issues?

I have added a small application to github illustrating the problem https://github.com/fin-steenbjerg-jyskebank-dk/test-reactive-jaxrs. Please read the readme file if you are interested. The resource is this https://github.com/fin-steenbjerg-jyskebank-dk/test-reactive-jaxrs/blob/main/src/main/java/dk/jyskebank/test/GreetingResource.java. If it contains one method then one exception is thrown, if it contains two methods another exception is thrown. The tests are executed by running the https://github.com/fin-steenbjerg-jyskebank-dk/test-reactive-jaxrs/blob/main/test-run.sh script.

The Quarkus version is 3.4.3 and I am using jdk17.

Comment: Would it be possible to share an example application? I want to check whether this is the specified behavior or simply a bug in our implementation of the spec

Comment: Good question.  I can see that with the `quarkus-resteasy` dependency the exception is consistent - `NotSupportedException`.  But the reactive one - with or without JSONB - shows the two different exceptions.  I don't have an answer but I would open a bug at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues.  For reference, Quarkus 3.5.0 has the same behavior.

Comment: @geoand I already have shared an example application

Comment: I have added the issue as a bug to quarkus as @stdunbar suggested. See [issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/36798)